# Liquibase Insert computedvalue with sql multiple row

Tags: sql, liquibase

I want to insert multiple rows to the xxx_table with liquibase.

```
<changeSet id="XXX" author="XXX">
    <comment>Add default values to xxx_table table</comment>
    <insert tableName="xxx_table">
        <column name="group_id"
                valueComputed="(SELECT group_id FROM subscriber)"/>
        <column name="business_name"
                valueComputed="(SELECT business_name FROM subscriber)"/>
        <column name="created_stamp" valueComputed="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"/>
        <column name="last_updated_stamp" valueComputed="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"/>
    </insert>
    <rollback/>
</changeSet>
```

Liquibase script fails because more than one row is returned from '(SELECT business name FROM subscriber)'. How can I insert multiple raw to a table?

Comment: You need to restrict the selection of rows to one by providing where clause with proper condition in your select statements.Select statements are bringing more than one value which is causing the failure

Comment: Please post the error.  Use logLevel=debug on the commandline or in your liquibase.properties and post the whole contents.  It is easier to do here is you would like: https://forum.liquibase.org/